# setTimeout function not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, settimeout

I am developing a mobile application, and I have to call a function after two seconds. I am using setTimeout, which is working properly in Chrome, but on my Samsung is not working. Here is the code.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
                            loadBooking(booking);
                            LocalStorageWrapper.add('currentBooking', currentBooking);
                            changeCircleColor(currentBooking, bookingsData.length);
                            $("#swiped").fadeIn('slow', 'linear');
                        }, 700);
```

Do you have an idea why is not working?

Comment: I suspect the code is erroneous if you're not seeing #swiped fade in. Why are you using a setTimeout? If it's because some of those vars/function/elements aren't available yet, then you should use some sort of callback. What do those functions do?

Comment: I am seeing #swiped fading in, but not after 700 ms or after other interval. All is working properly on phone, but I need to call those function after two seconds, which not happens on phone.

Comment: I am thinking that the background jobs are not working on phonegap, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: The functions are called immediately instead of after x ms? Did you try to set the timeout to 10000? What do you mean by background jobs?

Comment: Yes, the functions are called immediately, even if the timeout interval is 10000 but only on emulator/phone, in Chrome the function are called after 10 seconds.

Comment: Pretty sure I've used setTimeouts in Cordova without any problem. Is that your exact code? Is there any other code related that might be of interest? Where does the window.setTimeout live (what is the context in which it is set)?

Comment: Do you think that the version of Cordova could be a problem? I have to hide some elements, change them and then show them again. I use fadeOut and fadeIn, but those elements are changed before fadeOut to finish, so I need one or two seconds to wait, and then to change them and fadeIn. But I solved this problem using the callback of the fadeOut action, but I still don't know why the functions are called immediately.

Comment: Using the callback is the right way to do it. I think you should always avoid setTimeout/setInterval, unless you actually need a timer/clock type thing. Still, it should work (providing this is your code exactly). You could try other Cordova versions, maybe you've encountered a bug, maybe try `setTimeout(func, 2000); function func(){ doStuff() }` (makes no sense, but I'm out of ideas).

Comment: I'm having this issue on React-native for only some few android 7 devices. setTimeout run immediately instead of waiting after x ms. Just found 1 device can reproduce this issue.